# how to avoid permissionerror when opening registry keys with winreg in python?

Tags: python, permissions, key, registry, winreg

I'm trying to open a registry key

`(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render)`

in python with winreg for reading and writing purposes but i keep running into

> "PermissionError: [WinError 5] access is denied"

First I've manually changed permissions in the regedit (as described in [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/262464/how-to-gain-full-permissions-to-edit-protected-registry-keys/) tutorial) for the keys i needed. that works, but its uncomfortable. i also noticed that installing updates for example for graphics cards can delete old keys and create new ones, so you'd always have to adjust permissions after installing a update which is unpractical. running as admin doesn't help either.

```
import winreg

reg_hive = winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
main_key = r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render"

with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, reg_hive) as Hive:
    with winreg.OpenKey(
            Hive, main_key, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as RenderKey:

        get_subkey_tuple = winreg.QueryInfoKey(RenderKey)
        # this tuple counts sub_key starting with 1
        # we subtract -1 so we get the correct index for range()
        subkey_indices = get_subkey_tuple[0] - 1

        for i in range(0, subkey_indices):
            sub_key = winreg.EnumKey(RenderKey, i)
            final_key_string = main_key + "\\" + sub_key
            print(final_key_string)
            with winreg.OpenKey(Hive, final_key_string, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as local_key:
                pass
```

the "winreg.OpenKey" lines cause the Permissionerror (the ones i didn't change the permissions manually in the regedit yet). i'd like to open/read/write registry keys without having to adjust the permissions by hand.

---edit---
does the "reserved" parameter have anything to do with it? the documentation is pretty thin on that one.

only mentions it with 2 sentences:
"reserved is a reserved integer, and must be zero. The default is zero."
and
"reserved can be anything – zero is always passed to the API."
the later one is for winreg.SetValueEX() only.

Comment: did you tried to run your python code as an `administrator`?

Comment: i did try running as admin but didn't make a difference.

Comment: Well, if you don't have permission, you cannot do anything in your code to circumvent that.

Comment: then how does other software get the permission? the graphic card driver update for example deleted a old key and created a new one, i didn't have to change any permissions in the registry for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```py
    with winreg.OpenKey(
            Hive, main_key, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as RenderKey:
```

change `winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS` to `winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE` to edit it (which you indicate wanting to do in the comments but don't actually need it in the code) or `winreg.KEY_READ` if you don't need to write.
When you use `winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS`, you request permissions for everything you can do with a key, including creating subkeys, deleting subkeys and values and removing the key entirely.  For some reason the permissions aren't as strict when you want to simply set a value (or simply read the key).